# How to downcast without using a new variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

I only know of this way to downcast

```
let x = y as? subclass
x.subclassmethod()
```

But this introduce a new variable x, is there a way to just operate on y?

Most language would allow you to do this

```
((x)y).subclassmethod()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift way is to use parentheses

```
(y as? subclass)?.subclassmethod()
```

The second `?` is necessary to optional chain the expression.

Comment: Note that this also introduces a new variable although it is not explicitly assigned